# Android xml animations not working properly

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I have an Activity which has a **BottomNavigationView**.It has 2 items(Fragments).The first fragment has to enter from left and exit to the left.Similarly the second fragment has to enter from the right and exit to the right.Both the fragments enter correctly, but exits the opposite ways.Have a look here:

enter_from_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    >
</translate>
</set>
```

exit_to_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    >
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    >
</translate>
</set>
```

enter_from_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    >

</translate>
</set>
```

exit_to_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
     android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%">

</translate>
</set>
```

Code:(**Exit animations work oppositely for both fragments**)

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.sendSms:
                    FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left,R.anim.exit_to_left);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragcontainer,new SendSmsFragment());
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.receiveSms:
                    FragmentTransaction transaction1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction1.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_right);
                    transaction1.replace(R.id.fragcontainer,new ReceiveSmsFragment());
                    transaction1.commit();
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try exit_to_right: `transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left,R.anim.exit_to_right);`